# Runtime error 1004. cells not fully qualified I'm assuming

Tags: vba, excel

Right off the bat, I'm not stellar at VBA, and the code below may be riddled with errors in addition to what's stopping me from continuing. Basically I am trying to build a tree (not unlike a BOM) with data found in various other sheets in the workbook. Below is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim acreg As String, eonum As String
Dim wb As Workbook, wsrpt As Range
Dim wsgr As Range, wsassy As Range, wspd As Range


Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, khor As Integer, x As Integer
Dim kvert As Integer, j2 As Integer

Dim parenttemp As String, childtemp As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

acreg = "EK-PPT"
eonum = "E-123-0"
Set wsgr = wb.Worksheets("GEN_ARR").UsedRange
Set wsassy = wb.Worksheets("ASSY").UsedRange
Set wspd = wb.Worksheets("PART_DETAIL").UsedRange
Set wsrpt = wb.Worksheets("REPORT").UsedRange

i = 1
j = 1
j2 = 1
khor = 3
kvert = 1
x = 1

While wsgr(Cells(i, 2)).Value <> ""
If wsgr(Cells(i, 2)).Value = eonum And wsgr(Cells(i, 5)).Value = acreg Then
    parenttemp = wsgr(Cells(i, 1)).Value
    wsrpt(Cells(khor, kvert)).Value = parenttemp
    kvert = kvert + 1
    i = i + 1

    While wsassy(Cells(j, 1)).Value <> ""
        If wsassy(Cells(j, 2)).Value = parenttemp Then
                childtemp = wsassy(Cells(j, 1)).Value
                wsrpt(Cells(khor, kvert)).Value = childtemp
                parenttemp = childtemp
                kvert = kvert + 1
                j = j + 1

            While wsassy(Cells(j2, 1)).Value <> ""
            If wsassy(Cells(j2, 2)).Value = parenttemp Then
                childtemp = wsassy(Cells(j2, 1)).Value
                wsrpt(Cells(khor, kvert)).Value = childtemp
                parenttemp = childtemp
                kvert = kvert + 1
                j2 = 1
            Else
                j2 = j2 + 1
            End If
            Wend

            While wspd(Cells(x, 1)).Value <> ""
            If wspd(Cells(x, 2).Value) = childtemp Then
                childtemp = wspd(Cells(x, 1)).Value
                wsrpt(Cells(khor, kvert)).Value = childtemp
                khor = khor + 1
                x = x + 1
            Else
                x = x + 1
            End If
            Wend
        Else
            j = j + 1
        End If
        Wend

Else
    i = i + 1
End If
Wend


End Sub
```

I think this is because my cells aren't fully qualified because of sheet activation. is activating sheets necessary? Or can we point to these cells without having to activate?

any help would be greatly appreciated! thanks!

Comment: Title nailed it.  Everything that looks like `wsgr(Cells(i, 2)).Value` should look like `wsgr.Cells(i, 2).Value`

Comment: thank you so much! i knew I wasn't too far off!